# compactness of a set with 2 topologies

Tags: general-topology

if we have two topologies U and T on X such that U subset in T .then if (X,U) is not compact, then so is (X,T).
can someone prove it ? and give me some notes on compactness between subset of a set , topology in another...
Other question :is the set of rational numbers hausdorff?
And more quest can u write explicitly the set A , where A=(]a,b[ΠQ)U{x} where a,b,x in R where x is strictly between a and b

Comment: Just choose the same open cover of which one can not find an open subcover...

Comment: Given an open cover in $U$ it is also an open cover in $T$.

Comment: can u detail it mathematically?

Comment: @sarafkh Suppose $C\subset U$ is a cover for which there does not exist a finite subcover. Since $U\subset T$ it is clear that $C\subset T$. Therefore $(X,T)$ is not compact.

Comment: is the set of rationals T2?

Comment: @sarafkh It depends on the topology. It is T2 in the standard topology. Do you see why?

Comment: do u mean the usual topology on R? cz I have a quest if we have (Q,Tusual) and I select an open set in it ,then would it be UΠQ where U in Tusual or would it be only U?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open cover $\mathcal{O}$ of $X$ using $\mathcal{U}$-open sets that has no finite subcover, and as $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ that **very same** cover $\mathcal{O}$ shows that $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is also not compact.

As to the second unrelated question: if $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is Hausdorff, and $Y \subseteq X$ has the subspace topology, then $Y$ is also Hausdorff: if $y_1 \neq y_2$ are points in $Y$, we can find disjoint open subsets $U$ and $V$ containing them (in $X$), and then $U \cap Y$ and $V \cap Y$ are then subspace open and still disjoint.

Comment: can u plz answer my 3rd edited quest?

Comment: @sarafkh That's hardly readable; learn MathJax and write it as $A=(]a,b[ \cap \Bbb Q) \cup \{x\}$ for starters. Is $x$ rational or irrational? The latter I suppose, or the first part would have sufficed. $A$ is already explicit, how can it be more explicit?